# Synonym for personality in context of non-living things

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Something living has a personality or persona of its own. Similarly, is there a word that can be used in the case of describing a non-living thing, say, a portrait?

Comment: The word ***character*** is often used in this way, like *that chair made of antique reclaimed wood really has character*, or *this cutesy middle American small town really has some character*. That kind of thing.

Comment: in the same sense we can also use life as in the painting has life of it's own . 
What do u thing?

Comment: You can say that, but that is more *active*, involving decisions, whereas personalities and characters speak to inherent traits, or salient aspects of the object.

Comment: 'Personification'?

Answer (score 2):

I go for singularity (or singular), [meaning](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/singularity)

> 1. The quality or condition of being singular.
> 2. A trait marking one as distinct from others; a peculiarity.
> 3. Something uncommon or unusual.

The French language has a phrase which summarizes the notion of singularity, and that is

> *je ne sais quoi*,

which is [defined](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/je_ne_sais_quoi) as "an intangible quality that makes something distinctive or attractive."

In English we might say about something with singularity (such as a portrait),

> It has a certain something. I can't quite put my finger on it, but it's there just the same.

Answer (score 1):

We know personality is too much connected with people, maybe because it has the word "person" in it or maybe something else, so what we need is a word that means the same and can be used for things other than an actual person. I use [Individuality](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/individuality) because both a living or non-living thing can have individuality.

It means:

> distinctive or unique character or personality
>
> the qualities that distinguish one person or thing from another
>
> the state or quality of being a separate entity

All three of the above definitions impart separate shades of traits to the word. When used properly it can get the intent through.

> Example: A painting of great individuality

Also see, [Definition of individuality at dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/individuality)